# How to use javascript autocomplete with php remotely

Tags: javascript, php, autocomplete, cross-domain

I am trying to create a simple search form that would have autocomplete. The values for autocomplete are take from database that's on a different server. 
I have this:

```
<form action="smth.php" method="POST">
  <label>Tracking Tag</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tag" id="tag"  />
  <button class="submit btn btn-success" type="submit" name="search" value="Show">Show</button>
</form>
```

My little javascript is:

```
$("#tag").autocomplete({source: "suggest_tag.php", minLength:1});
```

Now I have this suggest_tag.php file that gets called.

```
<?php
    if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )
    exit;

    $data =    file_get_contents("http://xxx/suggest_tag.php?  tag=".$_REQUEST["term"]);
    echo $data;
?>
```

Script in http/xxx/suggest_tag.php is the following:

```
<?php
    if ( !isset($_GET['tag']) )
        exit;

    $conn = mysql_connect(**credentials**) or die('Not able to connect to db');
    $query = "select query;";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $data = array();
    if ( $result && mysql_num_rows($result) )
    {
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
        {
            $data[] = array("label"=>$row['tag'], "value"=>$row["tag"]);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

What am I  doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you getting any errors, or is your output wrong?

Comment: I am getting no autocomplete suggestions even though I know there is a record like that in a database.

Comment: I guess your source have to be data, and not an url, so you would have to make ajax calls to the php page, that then returns the data, and then you can use it.

Comment: Did you check if the pages have a correct output?

Comment: @Jerodev, I have checked my http/xxx/suggest_tag.php page. For **http/xxx/suggest_tag.php?cee** and it outputs this:
[{"label":"CEE 2015","value":"CEE 2015"},{"label":"CEE 2015","value":"CEE 2015"}].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I had a stupid syntax error inside the query, the rest works fine. SO that is a valid code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using custom data with the autocomplete. If you do this you need to overwrite the `select` and `focus` function as mentioned in [the documentation](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data).